# Order of different size element of a structure

Tags: c

I am currently wondering if there is a good way of ordering element of a structure if the elements have not the same size.

Which one of the following example is the best ?

**Example 1 :**

```
struct
{
   u8  my_u8;
   u8  my_u8_2;
   u32 mu_u32;
}
```

**Example 2 :**

```
struct
{
   u32 mu_u32;
   u8  my_u8_2;
   u8  my_u8;
}
```

Will the memory needed the same if I declare a structure in both cases ?

Comment: You can always check if `sizeof` to see how many bytes a struct will take.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ordering from objects with large alignment to small typically should produce the tightest structure, i.e. Example 2 is better. But in your case both examples will produce structs of the same size in most architectures.

Your example 1 requires 8 bytes:

```
+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| u8   | u8_2 | (padding since u32 must be aligned in a |
|      |      |  4-byte boundary)                       |
+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| u32                                                   |
|                                                       |
+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
```

Your example 2 also requires 8 bytes:

```
+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| u32                                                   |
|                                                       |
+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| u8   | u8_2 | (padding since the whole struct aligns  |
|      |      |  to 4-byte boundary since it has u32.)  |
+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
```

A bad example would be

```
struct {
    u8  my_u8;
    u32 my_u32;
    u8  my_u8_2;
};
```

which would require 12 bytes:

```
+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| u8   | (padding since u32 must be aligned in a 4-byte |
|      |  4-byte boundary)                              |
+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| u32                                                   |
|                                                       |
+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| u8_2 | (padding since the whole struct aligns to      |
|      |  4-byte boundary)                              |
+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
```

Comment: Agreed my example should be better with u32 u16 u8 u8 and u16 u32 u8 u8 (something like that)

Answer (score 2):

Only do this if it's absolutely crucial to minimise padding within your struct, e.g. if you have a large array of such structs and memory is tight, otherwise it's just premature optimization and code readability/maintainability will suffer.

If this really is the case then the general idea is to order the elements in decreasing order of size, so Example2 in your case.

Comment: It's what I thought... Thanks